# WSL Ubuntu why does cpanm install Perl5 modules in the wrong spot?

Tags: drivers, windows-subsystem-for-linux, perl, cpan

I have Ubuntu installed under Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2). There are Perl5 modules installed under /usr/share/perl/5.30.0 and I can access these with a plain `use` statement. But when I install new modules with cpanminus, it puts them in /home/*****/perl5/lib/perl5/, where the interpreter can't find them unless I have a `use lib` declaration at the top.  Is there some way to get cpanm to install them in the right spot?

Here is the relevant output of perl -V. IDK if the entries in %ENV were there before I used cpanm. Otherwise the installation is what came with the distro.

```
%ENV:                                                                                                                                 
PERL5LIB="/home/*****/perl5/lib/perl5"                                                                                  
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/*****/perl5"                                                                             
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/home/*****/perl5""                                                                    
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/*****/perl5"                                                                      
@INC:                                                                                                                 
/home/*****/perl5/lib/perl5/5.30.0/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi                                                    
/home/*****/perl5/lib/perl5/5.30.0                                                                                  
/home/*****/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi                                                           
/home/*****/perl5/lib/perl5                                                                                         
/etc/perl                                                                                                           
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0                                                                         
/usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0                                                                                        
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30                                                                                
/usr/share/perl5                                                                                                    
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30                                                                                 
/usr/share/perl/5.30                                                                                                
/usr/local/lib/site_perl                                                                                            
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `use lib` in your script, you could modify your perl search paths in your `~/.bashrc` file, like I do:

```
PERL5LIB="/home/*****/perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB:+:${PERL5LIB}}"; export PERL5LIB;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your environment, you have some settings from [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib). Various CPAN tools use this module to set installation locations for you can install modules as a non-privileged user.

```
PERL5LIB="/home/*****/perl5/lib/perl5"                                                                                  
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/*****/perl5"                                                                             
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/home/*****/perl5""                                                                    
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/*****/perl5"
```

These settings are likely in your shell profile file.

Inside your program, you can use that module to use those settings to adjust the module search path:

```
use local::lib;
```

You can load that from the command line too:

```
% perl -Mlocal::lib program.pl
```

But, you don't seem to want to use `local::lib` (and should clean those environment variables). With cpanm, you can specify the installation base with `-l`:

```
% cpanm -l /usr/share/perl/5.30.0 ...
```

You can remove the environment variables `PERL_MB_OPT` and `PERL_MM_OPT`, which tell *Build.PL* or *Makefile.PL* where to install things. If those aren't around, the various CPAN tools take their settings from the *perl* they use, and that seems to be what you want.